# How to open folder with C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I need to open an explorer window showing a specific folder, lets say `"C:\\Windows"` What function should I use to reach my goal? I'm using Windows so can use API, also I can use boost, but I can't use C++11.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "open a folder"? Are you trying to list the files in a folder?

Comment: I want something like a `system("explorer.exe")`

Comment: Oh, so just use the `/e,` option: `explorer.exe /e, <folder path>` and use `system`

Comment: @DreWMcGowen I do not recommend to use `system()` because it launches another processes and even program what use `system()` may be banned by antivirus.

Comment: Well, I think in this case, launching another process is unavoidable. And I've never heard of an antivirus blocking `system()`.

Comment: @DreWMcGowen I probbaly used wrong word. I also have never seen antivirus blocking program which uses `system()` but I have seen that it warns about probably unsafe stuff. I don't want to have such a warning about my software. Also launching process takes some time. What is more you need to wait for answer of that process. In this case these things don't make so much problems, but have you ever tried resource hacking, it is very easy to change `system` calls in compiled program and your software may be used as a hole in system by black-hats.

Comment: @DreWMcGowen I heard that thing about antiviruses too, I think it is not good to use `system()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` function to do this, rather than forcibly running Explorer yourself (what if the user has replaced Explorer as their default file manager, for example?).

```
LPCWSTR pszPathToOpen = L"C:\\Windows";
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
if (SUCCEEDED(SHParseDisplayName(pszPathToOpen, 0, &pidl, 0, 0)))
{
    // we don't want to actually select anything in the folder, so we pass an empty
    // PIDL in the array. if you want to select one or more items in the opened
    // folder you'd need to build the PIDL array appropriately
    ITEMIDLIST idNull = { 0 };
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlNull[1] = { &idNull };
    SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl, 1, pidlNull, 0);
    ILFree(pidl);
}
```

Alternatively, you can call `ShellExecute` on the folder directly to run its default action (which is normally to open in a browser window):

```
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, L"C:\\Windows", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: When using `ShellExecute ()`, you can (and should) set the verb to `"explore"` instead of relying on the default action: "*The following verbs are commonly used: ... **explore** Explores a folder specified by lpFile.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Citation for "should" ?

Answer (score 0):

An hour ago I just wrote similar function.

This function doesn't do 100% as you want, but you can use it to get that you want.
It opens explorer window and marks file you are pointing to. Lets say you specified `"C:\Windows\System32"` in this case you will have `"C:\Windows"` opened and `System32` marked. If you want to go inside you need to use something like `FindFirstFile`. If directory is empty, my offered solution wouldn't work...

```
bool ExplorerGoTo (const String &Path)
{
    TCHAR tcBuff[8] = {0};
    lstrcpyn(tcBuff, Path.c_str(), 5);

    String stParams = _T("/n, /select, ");

    if( lstrcmpi(_T("\\??\\"), tcBuff) == 0 )
    {
        stParams += (Path[4]);
    }
    else
    {
        stParams += Path;
    }

    String stExplorer = _T("C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe");

    //ExpandPath(stExplorer);
    if (stExplorer.empty ()) stExplorer = _T("explorer.exe");

    SHELLEXECUTEINFO shi = { 0 };

    shi.cbSize          = sizeof (SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    shi.lpVerb          = _T("open");
    shi.lpFile          = stExplorer.c_str ();
    shi.lpParameters    = stParams.c_str ();
    shi.nShow           = SW_SHOW;

    bool bRes = ShellExecuteEx( &shi );

    if( bRes == FALSE && GetLastError() != 0 )
    {
        Sleep(200);
        return ShellExecuteEx( &shi );
    }   
    return bRes;
}
```

And never use `system()`